# Multiple actions in trap in ksh

Tags: debugging, ksh, shell-trap

After `sudo su -`, I want to have both the username and timestamp in the k-shell history list. I have the command line:

```
trap 'who am i|cut -d" " -f1 |tr "\n" " " && date|read -s' debug
```

With this command, I expect something like:

`UserName Tue Oct 13 15:37:06 CDT 2015`
in the history list. However it shows only `Tue Oct 13 15:37:06 CDT 2015`

This seems to be executing the second action `date` only, and ignores or overrides the first action.

How can I have the username and timestamp in the history list?

**Noting that the reason why the user name is needed is that multiple users have the same impersonation right to the same service user.**

Comment: try making your multi command a function. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a simple solution:

1. Create a file *trapme* in the **service user**'s home directory with one line:

   who am i | cut -d" " -f1 |tr "\n" " " && date
2. Add one line in .profile:

   trap '~/trapme | read -s' debug

this will create a line after a command with the real user login and the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$ trap 'echo this; echo that' INT
$ sleep 10
^Cthis
that
$
```

If you need complicated commands, the usual way is to use `ksh -c 'compound | pipe | command'` but it can get pretty tricky with quoting.

(At least in bash, the subshell is capable of invoking the parent shell's functions, so you could define a function as the commenter suggested. Not tested this with `ksh`).

**UPDATE**

This works for me:

```
trap 'echo $(whoami|cut -d" " -f1 |tr "\n" " " && date)' INT
```

Consider doing

```
trap 'echo "$(id -un) $(date)"' INT
```

Or even

```
trap 'date "+$(id -un) %DT%T"' INT
```

Etc.

Comment: if I run`who am i|cut -d" " -f1 |tr "\n" " " && date`, it does give me what I want. The problem appears to be with the trap, or the read. Also how can I do what you suggested? the ^Cthis is a control-C, or it is a ^ and a C?

Comment: @Heinz added a few tested updates. `man date` should help getting the format desired

Comment: sehe, as I said, your examples work when you run it at the command line. I need the user's name and timestamp (the format is not important here) in the history list so we can trace who did what at what time.

Comment: sehe, my company's security blocks the access to your URL.

Comment: It "just works". Let me upload a recording: http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/8747946f-9e9b-4cdc-95a8-ad48b619b803/kshtest.mp4

Comment: I watched you recording, and did not see the user and date in the history.

Comment: Oh. Wait. I clearly saw both the username and the date in my recording, so you must be referring to some other history location. Why did you expect it there? Use [`script(1)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_(Unix)) or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Put all the commands whose output you want to pass to `read` into a group:

```
trap '{ who am i|cut -d" " -f1 |tr "\n" " "; date; }|read -s' DEBUG
```